# itemView trigger a custom event reaching the parrent

Tags: javascript, layout, triggers, marionette, event-bubbling

I have this code
http://jsfiddle.net/QRcF5/2/

```
$(function() {
    var Header = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: _.template('<h4>TEST</h4><button>EDIT</button>'),

        tagName: 'nav',

        triggers: {
            'click button': 'btn_clicked'
        }
    }),
    Layout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
        template: _.template('<header></header>'),

        regions: {
            header: 'header'
        },

        events: {
            'itemview:btn_clicked': 'clicked'
        },

        clicked: function() {
            alert('Ana are mere');
        }
    });

    layout = new Layout();
    $('body').append(layout.render().el);
    layout.header.show(new Header());
});
```

I'm using a layout with one ItemView (later I want a more complex nesting) and want to capture in LAYOUT the event  that is happening in the ITEMVIEW. It seems its not bubbling upwards or I'm doing something wrong here.

**UPDATE 1**
I've tried events, triggers (for the child) and on, events (for the parent) but I still can't get the event caught inside the parent.

I can use:

```
_.extend(App.vent, Backbone.Events);

Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    ....
    App.vent.trigger('btn_clicked');
    ....
});

Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    ....
    App.vent.on('btn_clicked', function() { doCoding(); });
    ....
});
```

But this way I'm breaking the encapsulation. Is there a way to keep the encapsulation by using Marionette triggers eventing and keep it all in the layout and not polluting the entire app ?

**UPDATE 2**

http://jsfiddle.net/QRcF5/5/

I've update the jsfiddle to use the _.extend(vent, Backbone.Events). If anyone has a better pattern for this, please let us know :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found the solution (buried somewhere in the documentation making some connections between layout, region and view) !

http://jsfiddle.net/QRcF5/6/

In the context of communication **ONLY** between the the parent (layout) and the child (itemView):

**1)** the child **triggers the custom event** (opposed to vent extend Backbone.Events - it only speaks to those who have access to it = encapsulation)

```
triggers: {
    'click button': 'custom_event:btn_clicked'
}
```

**2)** the parent listen to this event **having access** to the child with the **on('show',....)**

```
initialize: function() {
    var that = this; // needed for the listenTo which overrides 'THIS'

    this.header.on('show', function(view) {
        this.listenTo(view, 'custom_event:btn_clicked', that.clicked);
    });
},
```

Example:

```
layout = new Layout();
$('body').append(layout.render().el);
layout.header.show(new Header()); // Here we get access to child and its events
```

The (hidden) **power of Marionette**. (I mean when I say hidden, because being relatively new, the documentation is barebone and the **complex examples** are scarce).

With little perseverance anything can be accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

you should just return true and let the click bubble up in the DOM, see http://jsfiddle.net/aGaDY/ :

```
var Header = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: _.template('<h4>TEST</h4><button>EDIT</button>'),
  events: {
    'click button': 'btn'
  },
  btn: function () {
    return true;
  }
}),

Layout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template: _.template('<div>Before:</div><header></header><div>After:</div><div class="body">Body Goes Here</div>'),
    regions: {
        header: 'header'
    },
    events: {
        'click': 'btn_clicked'
    },
    btn_clicked: function () {
        alert('Ana are mere');
    }
});
layout = new Layout();
$('body').append(layout.render().el);
layout.header.show(new Header());
```

You can even remove the event handling on the ItemView completly, bubbling is the default behavior

**EDIT**:

If you want to be able to distinguish between different buttons click and prevent from polluting the global space with inner events that does not concern the application I can think of two options.

Move the data on the event target via jquery data function and event.target:

```
// In Header
bth:function(e){
  $(e.target).data("source", "myButton")
}
// ....
// in the Layout 
btn_click: function(e){
  if ($(e.target).data("source") === "myButton") this.doSomething()
}
```

Another option is that the layout will pass to Header a local backbone.Event extended object so communication will be private between the two.

I understand the issue of encapsulation, but I think that readability will be better in the global App.Vent that you suggested

Comment: @Symba You can put the login inside Header btn function, it is only important that you return true to enable bubbling.
I don't understand why this.on('click'... is required? what is not working in the jsfiddle?

Comment: sorry my mistake on that last comment.

Comment: I made myself misunderstood.

I want to trigger a custom event, because a simple click just wont do (too generic, I have many other clicks, buttons, etc) and if I put the html path ('click header button') then I'm creating a hard dependency on the html structure (which is highly undesirable).

PS: in backbone you don't need to return true, as you said "bubbling is the default behavior"

Comment: @Symba Added an Edit section, maybe it will help.

Comment: As you suggested and as I thought, vent it is still the lesser bad. But at least I will use the one within the module and not pollute the global App.Vent. Thank you for your time :D

Answer (score 0):

```
events: {
            'itemview:btn': 'btn_clicked'
        },
```

The itemview is not the thing being clicked. You need to specify an actual dom element like this:

```
events: {
            'click .someThingWithAClass': 'myFunction'
        },
```

However, if you want to listen to events that happen further down the track, you should probably just stick to the jquery `on` method. This will listen to anything that bubbles its way up, regardless of the ui that has been generated at the time that this view is rendered

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I'm using itemview in the way: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#itemremoved-event Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: What you would be doing is listening to events that occur on the itemview object that exists in JS code. Events that occur in the DOM aren't  the same as events that occur in javascript. If you're listening to clicks, that happen in the DOM, then you should do it using the bottom fragment of code that I wrote. If you're listening to events that happen on the marionette view object then you should use your way(my top one)

Comment: I'm searching for a communication between itemview and layout in Marionette (like we have an internal communication between model and view in Backbone)

Comment: **what link is that?** this is the official github of marionette https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette (you must have an older version of docs on your github)